# What is the application PlayAutoInstalls

Tags: applications, malware

I just updated my device (Xiaomi Mi Lite 10) and found an app with a name that concerned me.
The app name is "PlayAutoInstalls", seems a system app that I never used or installed, but I can't find information about it.

[image]

I never install anything outside Play Store, but this is not a guarantee of safety (malware) and I have the feeling that this one is a malicious app.
Any information about it's functionality (name is concerning), and if it's safe to remove?

Comment: App require no permission, except the ability to show notification.Is not clear to me how to show the package without installing anything

Comment: You would want to read this. https://www.programmersought.com/article/50995132696/ (follow from 2. heading). Also see https://www.reddit.com/r/Xiaomi/comments/764hir/what_is_this_pai_app_in_a1_that_cannot_be/

Comment: App names are nothing but text. More important is the app package name and it's signature. If you are curious about the app get it's APK file and upload it to virustotal.com - eg. using this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funnycat.virustotal

Comment: Possibly related: [Become an Android Partner](https://partner-android.appspot.com/home): "*Automatically push predetermined apps and other customization features to phones during setup without creating multiple carrier builds for the same device.*"

Comment: Anyone who wants to investigate, APKMirror has the Apk. https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/xiaomi-inc/pai-2/